# Pass entire dataset to Keras fit

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to pass the entire dataset to Keras `fit` function using `batch_size` parameter equals to length of the dataset, but it seems that process only 1 sample because under the `Epoch 1/50` print of the `fit` function I see `1/1` and not, for example, `500/500`, where 500 is the dataset length. How could I do?

Comment: It probably means one batch, since you now effectively you have each epoch with only one batch each.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress displayed in the terminal output is for batches, so what you see is expected: in that epoch you are processing batch 1 of 1, where that batch has 500 samples in it. You can of course recover the number of samples processed by multiplying by your batch size.